# Recommended practice for multiple MySQL Connections with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently accessing a SOAP Web Service through a PHP script using SoapClient. My script calls multiple subscripts (~30 a second) that each send a request and then pushes the response to a MySQL Database. My process attempts to emulate an "asynchronous" request/response mechanism.

In my subscript I connect to mysql and close the connection once it is complete. I'm running about 30 subscripts per second. I'm running into an issue where I am maxing out my MySQL connections.

I don't want to increase the maximum number of connections as I feel this is bad practice. Is there a better way to approach this problem? I am thinking I can somehow share a single mysql connection between the subscript and script.

Comment: You should have that many MySQL connections open at once, it sounds like you need some sort of client/server system, so you don't have all of these MySQL connections open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all subscripts are run in sequence, in one thread, then you can connect to MySQL once and pass this connection to all of them.

If subscripts are run in parallel, then it depend whether your MySQL library is thread safe or not. If it is, then you can pass one connection to all of them. But if not, you have no choice than one connection per script. This information should be mentioned in it's documentation.

If you need to run only some of the scripts in parallel and some can wait a while, then you can prepare pool of few connections (10 or so) and run only 10 scripts at once. When one script ends, you launch next and reuse old connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try connection pooling. I am not sure whether this is possible in php and whether there are frameworks already available for that.

If its not available You can use a Singleton class which contains a list of connections. Let the connections be closed by this class if its idle for N seconds. This means that your 30 subscripts can reuse connections which are not used by other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mysqli_pconnect? How do you spawn your sub processes? Can't you open the database connection in the main process and pass it to the sub processes? Any code examples of what you are doing?

Comment: I'm using exec to call the sub processes.The script is executed via cron. As a temporary fix, I changed the my.conf to kill sleeping processes after 30 seconds instead of ~20 minutes.